# JSP: EL is not evaluated (Instead of the value the variable "$message" is shown)

Tags: jsp, el

I have a problem with evaluating EL on a JSP page.
Instead of the value "Hello world!" I see the variable "$message".

I've tried to find the possible reasons and solutions for this problem:

1. **Application server.** Checked the application server - I use Tomcat 8.0.28 - it should support JSP 2.0. I also tried to create a new simple spring mvc application from scratches - and the EL was evaluated in that case.
2. **web.xml descriptor** I use "web-app_3_1.xsd".
3. **Page directive isELIgnored** I tried to add this directive (<%@ page isELIgnored=”true|false” %>) to JSP page and it worsened the situation - this expression and the whole html code was shown on the page.
4. I also tried to add the following code to the web.xml

   ```
   <jsp-config>
   <jsp-property-group>
       <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
       <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
   </jsp-property-group>
   ```

Nothing helps :)

Perhaps the problem maybe somehow related to pom.xml because there are too many dependences which can be in conflict.

Any help is highly appreciated.

[project structure (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T16Ee.png)

testController.jsp

```
package net.kuriculo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class testController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
        return "test";
    }
    }
```

test.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>${message}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <display-name>kuriculo</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>kuriculo</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>kuriculo</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.kuriculo</groupId>
    <artifactId>kuriculo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <!-- Spring Security is based on Spring 3.0.7 -->
        <!--<spring.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>-->
        <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <jersey.version>1.18.1</jersey.version>
        <org.slf4j.version>1.7.7</org.slf4j.version>
        <org.hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</org.hibernate.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <org.hsqldb.version>2.3.2</org.hsqldb.version>
        <commons-dbcp.version>1.4</commons-dbcp.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <org.eclipse.jetty.jetty-maven-plugin.version>9.1.1.v20140108</org.eclipse.jetty.jetty-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>


    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>2.2.1</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${org.eclipse.jetty.jetty-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:https://github.com/nshkuratova/KURICULO.git</developerConnection>
    </scm>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Huh? Spring Jdbc is suddenly marked as provided by spring-orm? -->
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <!-- jersey-spring uses spring 2.5, we want to use 3.x instead -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hsqldb.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-dbcp.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

<!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.187</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: try to change the @RequestMapping URL to something else than "/test". Since the JSP is also called test if might be causing a naming conflict.

Comment: I tried to change - still the problem remains. Nevertheless, thx for advise!

Answer (score 0):

In web.xml your servlet definition is missing a init-param to load the spring configuration file.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>kuriculo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/kuriculo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>    
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

also remove url-pattern "*.jsp"  and replace with "/*"

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>kuriculo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```